# How to check if Firebase local cache is synchronized?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A Node.js app needs to write some data to database and exit. 
But in Firebase, once the database connection is established, it won't let the app to exit.

Solutions to force exit (`app.delete()` and `process.exit()`, suggested in similar questions) work when called with some delay. I guess that's the time required to flush the local cache to database.

In order to force exit, it needs to make sure if the locally cached data is synchronized with the server. So, how to check when the local cache is synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API call to determine if the local write queue is empty.

The only way to detect this situation is to write a value and [wait for its completion listener to be called](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-completion-callback).

```
ref.push().set("Writing extra data", function(error) {
  if (error) {
    alert("Data could not be saved." + error);
  } else {
    alert("Data (including any previous writes) saved successfully.");
  }
});
```

Since write operations from a single client are guaranteed to be called in order, you can be certain that all write operation from before have also been committed at this point.